# Getting installation error while installing firebase in angular project

Tags: angular, firebase, angular-cli-v7

In my angular project I have to use firebase SDK for that I have to install firebase into my project. I tried to install it in my angular project using command "npm install angular-firebase --save". It throws this error:

```
> grpc@1.10.1 install E:\MyAngularApp\my-angular-app\node_modules\grpc
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library

node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not installable for grpc@1.10.1 and node@8.12.0 (node-v57 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
node-pre-gyp ERR! Hit error read ECONNRESET
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: read ECONNRESET
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:622:25)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17134
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\mo388682\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library" "--module=E:\\MyAngularApp\\my-angular-app\\node_modules\\grpc\\src\\node\\extension_binary\\node-v57-win32-x64-unknown\\grpc_node.node" "--module_name=grpc_node" "--module_path=E:\\MyAngularApp\\my-angular-app\\node_modules\\grpc\\src\\node\\extension_binary\\node-v57-win32-x64-unknown"
gyp ERR! cwd E:\MyAngularApp\my-angular-app\node_modules\grpc
gyp ERR! node -v v8.12.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\mo388682\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=E:\MyAngularApp\my-angular-app\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v57-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=E:\MyAngularApp\my-angular-app\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v57-win32-x64-unknown' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (E:\MyAngularApp\my-angular-app\node_modules\grpc\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:915:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17134
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "E:\\MyAngularApp\\my-angular-app\\node_modules\\grpc\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd E:\MyAngularApp\my-angular-app\node_modules\grpc
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v8.12.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.7.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\mo388682\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=E:\MyAngularApp\my-angular-app\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v57-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=E:\MyAngularApp\my-angular-app\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v57-win32-x64-unknown' (1)
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.7 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.7: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! grpc@1.10.1 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the grpc@1.10.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you didn't already, try installing Windows build tools: https://www.npmjs.com/package/windows-build-tools

```
npm install --global windows-build-tools
```

or

```
yarn global add windows-build-tools
```

Comment: then use
 npm install firebase @angular/fire --save